# Pattern matching of remainders in long division

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a working algorithm to determine if a fraction is infinite repeating and which digits are repeating:

```
std::vector<integer_type> rd, dg;
integer_type d ( m_numer ), r;

do {

    integer_type q, aux;

    rd.push_back ( r = ( aux = _remquo<T, GCD, CHKOP> () ( d, m_denom, q ) ) < zero_ ?
                       integer_type ( -aux ) : aux );
    dg.push_back ( q < zero_ ? integer_type ( -q ) : q );

    d = op_multiplies() ( base, r );

} while ( ! ( r == zero_ || std::find ( rd.rbegin() + 1, rd.rend(), r ) != rd.rend() ) );
```

**Notes:**

- `rd` contains the remainder digits
- `dg` contains the decimal result digits
- `_remquo` integer divides the first and second operand and stores the remainder in the third parameter, ignore the template parameters
- `base` can be considered as `10` for decimal value
- `m_numer` is the numerator of a fraction
- `m_denom` is the denominator of a fraction

**Question:**

I want to get rid of at least `std::find ( rd.rbegin() + 1, rd.rend(), r ) != rd.rend() )`, i.e. I want to detect if a remainder have already appeared before and at best (to get rid of the `rd` vector as well) the distance between the last digit from right to left to the first repeating digit in `rd`.

The problem is, that I want to analyze digits with a *HUGE* repeating digit sequence like [`1083448249/12172166`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1083448249%2F12172166) within a reasonable time (a time without spending to reverse search a remainder vector).

Does somebody has any ideas?

Comment: Isn't it easier to directly compute the repeating digits, rather than actually do the long division to detect the repeating digits.

Comment: @JSF You're welcome to show me any other algorithm to do that. I need both the final result as well as the repeating digits and (if any) the non repeating digits directly after the point. `13/30` => 0.4(3)

Comment: @HeikoSchäfer The problem can be reduced to `1/N` case. And for that case read this: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51549.html (which can be generalized to any base).

Comment: @freakish Thanks, for the link. I will go through it :)

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Decimal_expansion_and_recurrence_sequence), the "if" can be solved by prime factorisation. You can also find the length of the repetend algebraically, so you know when you've found it. Whether it is solvable in a reasonable time is another question, of course.

Comment: Yeah, this is done by prime factorization. And unfortunately I have no idea how efficient the method is (compared to long division), so yeah, you have to check it.

Comment: Let's assume the long division would be efficient enough, is there a way to get rid of the build of the `remainder vector` and the subsequent reverse search through it? I have to admit, I developed that algorithm on paper while I have been entirely off (no PC and no internet at thta time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute the digits of the decimal expansion directly, without bignums. Use Floyd's cycle detection method to figure out the period. In Python (cycle detection code courtesy of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def floyd(f, x0):
    tortoise = f(x0)
    hare = f(f(x0))
    while tortoise != hare:
        tortoise = f(tortoise)
        hare = f(f(hare))
    mu = 0
    tortoise = x0
    while tortoise != hare:
        tortoise = f(tortoise)
        hare = f(hare)
        mu += 1
    lam = 1
    hare = f(tortoise)
    while tortoise != hare:
        hare = f(hare)
        lam += 1
    return (lam, mu)


def repeating_decimal(n, d):
    q, r = divmod(n, d)
    decimal = [str(q), '.']
    period, first_repeat = floyd(lambda r: 10 * r % d, r)
    for i in range(first_repeat + period):
        q, r = divmod(10 * r, d)
        decimal.append(str(q))
    return '{}({})'.format(''.join(decimal[:2 + first_repeat]), ''.join(decimal[2 + first_repeat:]))


print(repeating_decimal(1, 75))
print(repeating_decimal(1083448249, 12172166))
```

Comment: OMG! Ok, it is python and another algorithm, but I think I will convert it into C++ and will give it a try :)

Comment: @HeikoSchäfer Most comfortable language for me to throw hacks at the wall in. There's an opportunity for simplification when you inline the lambda into the cycle detector.

Comment: you made my day :) I've converted it to C++ and integrated it (yet even unoptimized) in my code als **ALL** test cases run without errors! Thanks :-)